# MYSQL Warning in Client but Error in JDBC Connection from Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, databricks

I am writing a spark code to insert into a mysql table from a dataframe and I am getting an error

```
df_to_write.write.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbc_url).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")\
          .option("dbtable", tbl_name).option("user", DBUser).option("password", DBPassword)\
          .option("numPartitions",32).mode('append').save()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 170, 10.151.244.77, executor 0): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:00' for column
```

This I found out because of the value of column being 1970-01-01 00:00:00

However if i run the insert statement in mysql workbench its a warning, and the values gets inserted as 0000

example as below:

```
create table test_time (processing_ts timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL);

insert into test_time values ('1990-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000'),('1990-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000'),('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000');
```

the values from the output of the table is as below

```
1990-01-01 00:00:00
1990-01-01 00:00:00
0000-00-00 00:00:00     --> no error only warning and changed the value to 0000:00:00 00:00:00
```

Wanted to know what setting can i apply on the spark to get the same behaviour, i.e. there should be no error and the values should be set as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
Is there anyway to apply the insert ignore option in spark while writing to table.

As per the comment, pasting the code for simulation

SQL

```
mysql> create table test (processing_ts timestamp null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+---------------------+
| processing_ts       |
+---------------------+
| 1997-02-28 10:30:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1970-01-01 00:00:00',)], ['processing_ts'])
df2 =  df.select(f.to_timestamp(df.processing_ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('processing_ts'))

db_host = '127.0.0.1'
DBName = 'test'
jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{}/{}".format(db_host ,DBName)
DBUser = 'XXXXXX'
DBPassword = 'XXXXXXX123'
tbl_name = 'test'

df2.write.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbc_url).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")\
          .option("dbtable", tbl_name).option("user", DBUser).option("password", DBPassword)\
          .option("numPartitions",32).mode('append').save()
```

Comment: Provide the Schema of the data frame using ```df_to_write.printSchema``` and MySQL column datatype for which you are facing the issue.

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola added the steps to simulate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range for TIMESTAMP values is `1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000` to `2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999` [MySql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

The JDBC driver might not handle the same and hence it is aborting the insert job. The only thing here you can do is to replace the timestamp `1970-01-01 00:00:00` with some another dummy timestamp before inserting or else convert the datatype of the column processing_ts to DATETIME since the supported range is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`.

Comment: I understand the limit of the TIMESTAMP field, I wanted to understand why if i run the same insert from the client (mysql workbench) doesnt result in error rather it truncates the dates as shown in example above. Also is there any option to ignore these errors while loading from spark

Comment: As I said, it seems like the JDBC driver you are using to load data from spark doesn't handle the above case, and hence throws the error. So, its not a spark issue rather the driver you are using to load. Either replace the timestamp with dummy timestamp or change the target column datatype to DateTime. To debug further, specify the driver class or jar you are using to load data into MySQL from spark.